# how to choose only one situation by conditional cases

Tags: beamer, conditionals

environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
```

There is an idea that create a new CS, for example \modela like this:

```
\modela{enumerate}{#2}
```

would expand as follow:

```
\begin{frame}
     \begin{enumerate}
          #2
        \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
```

while

```
\modela{description}{#2}
```

can be expanded as:

```
\begin{frame}
     \begin{description}
          #2
        \end{description}
\end{frame}
```

Any approach to fulfill this command by conditional command instead of the \if command sequence, because of not only two options? Thanks very mcuh!

Comment: Instead of "There is an idea that create a new CS", I assume you mean "I would like to create a new command".

Comment: `\newcommand{\modela}[2]{\begin{frame}
                            \begin{#1}#2\end{#1}
                        \end{frame}
                        }    
`?  Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Zarko Far too simple ;)

Comment: @TeXnician, I prefere simple ... but i didn't test if suggestion not work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple version with kind of control over the input (it will only allow some specific environments instead of passing the environment name directly). You can add more cases (see `interface3.pdf`, page 39).

[image: beamer doc]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \c_enum_tl
\tl_set:Nn \c_enum_tl {enumerate}
\tl_new:N \c_desc_tl
\tl_set:Nn \c_desc_tl {description}
\tl_new:N \l__hezilun_tmp_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\modela}{m m}{
    \begin{frame}
    \tl_set:Nn \l__hezilun_tmp_tl {#1}
    \tl_case:Nn \l__hezilun_tmp_tl {
        \c_enum_tl {\begin{enumerate}#2\end{enumerate}}
        \c_desc_tl {\begin{description}#2\end{description}}
    }
    \end{frame}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \modela{enumerate}{
        \item Test
        \item Test
    }
    \modela{description}{
        \item[T] est
        \item[Test] Quack
    }
\end{document}
```

*Update:* If you want to have an error branch, just use

```
\tl_case:NnF \l__hezilun_tmp_tl {
    \c_enum_tl {\begin{enumerate}#2\end{enumerate}}
    \c_desc_tl {\begin{description}#2\end{description}}
}{Environment not allowed}
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my comment (content of document is stolen from *TeXnician* answer):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand{\modela}[2]{\begin{frame} \begin{#1}#2\end{#1} \end{frame} } 

\begin{document}
    \modela{enumerate}{
        \item Test
        \item Test
    }
    \modela{description}{
        \item[T] est
        \item[Test] Quack
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And a `\modela{frame}{}` or `\modela{document}{}` breaks it :(

Comment: :(, well this hasn't been asked ... (at least I din't understand question on this way). but you solve all this cases in your answer, or not? :)

Comment: Yeah, I do, but the user has to take the trouble and manually define all cases. I think both answer have their drawbacks and for the responsible user your solution seems kind of easier.

Comment: to be honest, I don't like such "inventions". On long therm they make only troubles ... (when you forget, what this mean, where is defined etc). Far better is use standard, well documented LaTeX code for which, if it become necessary can ask here what is going wrong (if this happens).

Comment: although  as a TeXer I would prefer use as basic as it can, it is a handy way for others who don't understand Tex and co-edit with the same beamer. In fact, a simplified command environments would be linked to willing acceptance for new users.